# Creating a folder in my personal Locker using Desire2Learn's REST APIs

Tags: desire2learn

How do I create a new folder (called "test") in my personal locker using Desire2Learn's REST API? I've tried this request, but it doesn't work:

```
POST /d2l/api/le/1.0/locker/mylocker/?x_a={appID}&x_c={appSig}&x_b={myUserID}&x_d={myUserSig}&x_t={time) HTTP/1.1
Host: myHost.com
Accept: */*
Content-type: application/json

{ "test" }
```

The server sends me back a 200 status, but also tells me "an unexpected error occurred". I've tested all the auth parameters with other routes, and they seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly unusual call;

The JSON data has to be just like this:

```
"test"
```

Not:

```
{ "test" }
```

There is an [example in the docs](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/locker.html#post--d2l-api-le-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-locker-myLocker-%28string-path%29) of this but it is recent.